# A problem after changing friend function to member function in C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function

To overload operator `+`, I first implement that as `friend` function + normal function

```
class Cents
{
private:
  int m_cents;

public:
  Cents(int);
  int getCents() const;
  friend Cents operator+(const Cents&, const Cents&);
};

Cents::Cents(int cents)
  : m_cents{cents}
{}

int Cents::getCents() const
{
  return m_cents;
}

Cents operator+(const Cents &c1, const Cents &c)
{
  return Cents(c1.getCents() + c.getCents());
}

Cents operator+(const Cents &c, int v)
{
  return Cents(c.getCents()+v);
}

Cents operator+(int v, const Cents &c)
{
  return Cents(v+c.getCents());
}

int main()
{

  Cents c1{1};
  Cents c2{2};
  Cents c{c1+c2};
  Cents c3{c+3};
  Cents c4{4+c3};
  std::cout << c.getCents() << '\n';
  std::cout << c3.getCents() << '\n';
  std::cout << c4.getCents() << '\n';
  return 0;

}
>>>
3
6
10
```

It works well. But when I use a member function to replace the `friend` function, error raises

```
class Cents
{
private:
  int m_cents;

public:
  Cents(int);
  int getCents() const;
  Cents operator+(const Cents&);
};

Cents::Cents(int cents)
  : m_cents{cents}
{}

int Cents::getCents() const
{
  return m_cents;
}

Cents Cents::operator+(const Cents &c)
{
  return Cents(m_cents + c.getCents());
}

Cents operator+(const Cents& c, int v)
{
  return Cents(c.getCents()+v);
}

Cents operator+(int v, const Cents& c)
{
  return Cents(v+c.getCents());
}

int main()
{

  Cents c1{1};
  Cents c2{2};
  Cents c{c1+c2};
  Cents c3{c+3};
  Cents c4{4+c3};
  std::cout << c.getCents() << '\n';
  std::cout << c3.getCents() << '\n';
  std::cout << c4.getCents() << '\n';
  return 0;

}
>>>
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'Cents')
  Cents c4{4+c3};
```

If `Cents c4{4+c3};` and `std::cout << c4.getCents() << '\n';` are removed, the rest code works fine

```
int main()
{
  Cents c1{1};
  Cents c2{2};
  Cents c{c1+c2};
  Cents c3{c+3};
//  Cents c4{4+c3};
  std::cout << c.getCents() << '\n';
  std::cout << c3.getCents() << '\n';
//  std::cout << c4.getCents() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
>>>
3
6
```

I guess it's because the compiler tries to resolve `4+c3` with the member function `Cents operator+(const Cents&);` and it can't use an `int` to call that function. But why can't the compiler use the normal function `Cents operator+(int v, const Cents &c)` to resolve `4+c3` as it did for `Cents c3{c+3};` using  `Cents operator+(const Cents &c, int v)`?

--- update ---

I am using Clion on macOS, but when I use an online compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler
the code (member function + normal function) compilers and runs successfully. But the online compiler also raises a warning

```
About • FAQ • Blog • Terms of Use • Contact Us • GDB Tutorial • Credits • Privacy
© 2016 - 2021 GDB Online
Language

    main.cpp

    input

main.cpp:54:14: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:                   
main.cpp:38:7: note: candidate 1: Cents operator+(const Cents&, int)                                                                                                                 
main.cpp:33:7: note: candidate 2: Cents Cents::operator+(const Cents&)                                                                                                               
3                                                                                                                                                                                    
6                                                                                                                                                                                    
10
```

My follow-up question, since the `friend` function and normal function doesn't need a specific object to call the function, thus, they won't have parameters ordering issue. Does this make us prefer `friend` function or normal function over a member function when we are overloading an operator in C++?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Most C++ gurus will tell you that a non-friend non-member version of the operator overload function is superior as it improves encapsulation. The function doesn't need to be a member to do its job, so it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You dropped a `const` during the migration, should be `Cents operator+(const Cents&) const`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9f3f98ce3911c80).